# Why I can't update my current index state in Swiper Slide using React

Tags: reactjs

I'm still very new to React and probably Swiper, too, I'm trying to implement it into my app, but I don't know why I can't update my current active index state whenever I change the slide.
I don't know what I did wrong, I hope someone can give me some newbie explanation.

My flow: Whenever I change the slide, it'll get the new `current index` and set it into the `swiperState`, so the state will be updated.

Here's my code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import './home.css'
import { supabase } from '../../supabaseClient'
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react'
import SwiperCore, { Pagination,Navigation } from 'swiper';
import 'swiper/css'

SwiperCore.use([Pagination,Navigation]);
function Home(){
    
    const [animeDetail, setAnimeDetail] = useState([])
    const [swiperIndex, setSwiperIndex] = useState(0)

    useEffect(async ()=>{
        fetchAnime()
    }, [])


    async function fetchAnime() {
        const { data } = await supabase
            .from ('anime')
            .select ()
            setAnimeDetail(data)
    }

    return (
        <>
        <div className="spacer">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div className="home-section">
            <h2>Home Page</h2>
            <Swiper
            initialSlide = {4}
            centeredSlides={true}
            slidesPerView={7}
            spaceBetween={10}
            loop={true}
            pagination={false} 

            // I use onActiveIndexChange to track current active index
            // and update its state using setSwiperIndex

            onActiveIndexChange={index => setSwiperIndex(index)}
            navigation={true} className="mySwiper">
                {animeDetail.map((element, i)=> 
                    (
                    <SwiperSlide key = {i}>
                        <img src={element.anime_image}/>
                    </SwiperSlide>
                    )
                    )}
            </Swiper>
        {/* I tried to call it down here to see whenever I change my slide, will it update the index through console log, but it doesn't */}
        {console.log(swiperIndex)}
        </div>
        </>
    )

}
export default Home
```

Comment: You can see the images, and you can slide but you can not update swiperIndex right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, I can still see the image, slide the image, but can't update the swiperIndex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I can see `onActiveIndexChange` method gives you a SwiperCore object, not the current index. So you should update your state with `activeIndex` attribute of that object. Like

> onActiveIndexChange={(swiperCore) => {
> setSwiperIndex(swiperCore.activeIndex);
> }}

Comment: Ah thank you for pointing out the SwiperCore object, I never noticed it from my perspective. So that's why it'll not update correctly, hence I just thought I do something wrong. Thank you again.